# In-app Billing : confirm refund notification

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Last week, I made a series of test purchasing in-app, everything is going well. However, i've cancel my command on checkout, since this, google play send me cancel notification continually.

Apparently googleplay does not understand my confirmation and notify me in continuous loop.

in onPurchaseStateChanged, after JSON parsing :

```
ArrayList<String> confirmations = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Trans p : transactions)
{
    [...]
    if (p.purchaseState.ordinal() == PurchaseState.CANCELLED.ordinal())
         confirmations.add(p.notificationId);
}
if (!confirmations.isEmpty())
{
    final String[] notifyIds = confirmations.toArray(new String[confirmations.size()]);
    confirmNotifications(context, notifyIds);
}
```

.

```
public static void confirmNotifications(Context context, String[] notifyIds) 
{
    final Intent intent = createIntent(context, Action.CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFY_IDS, notifyIds);
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What service are you trying to start here? Your own? Eventually you need to bind to the Market/Play Store's billing service and call `sendBillingRequest()` with a properly populated `Bundle`. Does your code do this?

Comment: Yes, i've no problem for purchase confirmation with same method

Comment: Ok, seems to be due to captive network / proxy at my work. At home cancel notification were confirmed without problem. On the other side, i dont understand why purchase confirmation are confirmed but not cancel confirmation (At work)